# Recommended approach for handling errors across process using AIDL (Android)

Tags: java, android, aidl, android-binder

I have a binder service and a client that live in different processes.  Using AIDL, when the client calls into my remote binder service, there are times that I need to relay an error (exception) back to the client.

However, from my understanding, this is not possible.  I tried throwing a "RemoteException" from my binder service to see what will happen, and I get

> Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)

in my logcat.

Since it looks like this is not possible, what is the best approach for informing the client of an error? I was thinking I can just convert my AIDLs to use C-style interfaces in which I just return an error code (and 0 on success), but this looks ugly.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: "I have a binder service and a client that live in different processes" -- why?

Comment: I've created a system service for AOSP (Android Open Source Project) much like the PackageManager in which it runs all the time in the background.  I've created an AIDL interface for my clients to interact with my service.

Comment: OK, that's reasonable. Have you looked at how other system services handle it? I know that some of the exceptions that get raised are actually by the hand-rolled Java class that is what we in the SDK see as the system service (e.g., `AccountManager`). But I would have to think that some exceptional circumstances could occur in the system process, and so there's gotta be an existing pattern for this somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your remote method can return a [`Parcel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) that contains the result data or an Exception if there is an error. See the [`Parcel#writeException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeException%28java.lang.Exception%29) method. I believe that this is how Android exceptions make it back when performing actions on a `ContentProvider` that lives in another process. There are many ways to return the result data including using the `Bundle` class.

Your manager class can hide the implementation details by unparcelling and returning the data or throwing the unparcelled exception so users never interact with the `Parcel`.

[Here is a link to the source for `Parcel#writeException`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#L1307).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I like the idea, but unfortunately, it doesn't support custom exceptions.  I am thinking that I might go with changing all of my AIDLs to return a Bundle. The Bundle will include a status code + the object to be returned (if any).

Comment: If you look in the platform source at how Parcel#writeException is implemented it is actually quite simple (I added a link in the answer). They write an int into the Parcel representing the exception type or 0 if no exception has occurred, then read the int on the other side and throw that exception. If you follow their pattern you can throw any custom exception you like.